# Determine x-coordinate of 3rd point on CIRCLE from y-coordinate and 2 other points

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, circles

I'm trying to construct an arc for a custom engineering curve.  Say that the arc is on a circle having points $A: (x_1, y_1)$, $B: (x_2, y_2)$, and $C: (x_3, y_3)$, where $x_1 < x_2 < x_3$ and $y_1 < y_2 < y_3$.  Also, $y_1 = mx_1$, where $m$ is a constant.  The center and radius are unknown.  How do I solve for $x_1$?  Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: Two points are not enough to determine a circle.  So your question has no answer.

Comment: @Robin's Premium Coffee, there are two points AND half of a third.

Comment: What equations would you have to solve then ?

Comment: @user20730: You need to indicate more explicitly, what data is given. If you have only $x_2$, $y_2$, $x_3$, $y_3$ and $m$ then you cannot find $x_1$, because you have only two points of circle and some line that crosses circle, which is insufficient to find circle center and radius and intersection point with the line.